# Handling address bar URLs using React and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, reactjs, mod-rewrite

I am learning ReactJS and while creating a test app, I faced a problem. I am using `.htaccess` to redirect all invalid URLs to `index.html` for further processing. But something keeps breaking every time I enter an URL with more than one slash in it.

**How to Replicate**

***.htaccess***:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
```

***index.html***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-root"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***app.jsx***:

*(I am transpiling using Babel in a Gulp build. For test purposes, you can transpile online at http://babeljs.io/repl/)*

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const TestPage = () => <span>{window.location.href}</span>

ReactDOM.render(
    <TestPage />
    ,document.getElementById('react-root')
)
```

So, when visiting `http://localhost/anything` it works fine.
But, if I go to `http://localhost/anything/something` or `http://localhost/anything/something/else` then it breaks. The server still returns `index.html` by the way which gets loaded in the browser fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could possibly be a combination of several small issues, but have a look in your network tab to see if there's any problems loading. From your example `app.js` seems to be loading relatively and is not handled inside the rewrite. Try make all the links to assets absolute, i.e. `/app.js`

Comment: That worked like a charm! I checked the network tab and you were right. The assets being served by relative paths were not being affected by rewrite. I'll try and learn more about the hows and whys of it. Thanks a lot.